# Personality trait for "someone who waits to find who's in a position of power and then gets behind them"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

The question :)

Bonus points if the word implies that they try not to antagonize anybody. It's like a guy betting on the horse that's winning, but keeping his options open about changing his bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say **fickle** works quite well here, but you would need to make sure the exact meaning can be ascertained from context.

> Marked by lack of steadfastness, constancy, or stability : given to erratic changeableness [Source: Merriam- Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fickle#synonyms)

In my experience, fickle is usually used to describe someone who "backs the winning horse".

E.g.

> He supported England last week, but now Wales are at the top of the word rankings, he'd claiming to support them. He's so fickle!

---

For your "bonus", I would suggest the phrase:

> **Hedge your bets** - to protect yourself against loss by supporting more than one possible result or both sides in a competition [Source: Cambrudge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hedge-your-bets)

Or, that he doesn't want to:

> **Put all his eggs in one basket** - If someone puts all their eggs in one basket, they put all their effort or resources into doing one thing so that, if it fails, they have no alternatives left. [Source: Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-all-your-eggs-in-one-basket)